# how to get all the text in TEXTBOXES which are created dynamically concatenated to one single MESSAGE BOX

Tags: vb.net

iam trying to concatenate the text in the text boxes to get appeared in the messge box i got struck about the syntax i was supposed to use instead or using `FOR` statements which displaying multiple message box rather than one message box revealing the text in all text boxes.

Comment: Er...could you expand a bit on your question, please? Explain what is happening and what you want to happen. Show the relevant pieces of code.

Comment: I used one TEXT BOX to get the input from the user and one submit button (for dynamically displaying the text boxes according to the user given number) now my intention is to how to get the information in all that TEXT BOXES in a concatenated form to one SINGLE MESSAGE BOX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not clear what you want but... I show you how to iterate each textbox on a ControlCollection to get the control-text.

```
Dim AllTexts As String() =
    (From tb As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
     Order By tb.Name Ascending Select tb.Text).ToArray

MsgBox(String.Join(" ", AllTexts))
```

Comment: I used one TEXT BOX to get the input from the user and one submit button (for dynamically displaying the text boxes according to the user given number) now my intention is to how to get the information in all that TEXT BOXES in a concatenated form to one SINGLE MESSAGE BOX.